# Rendered attribute not updating on subsequent ajax calls

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a `p:commandButton` that calls a view-scoped bean method. The method sets two string fields called `textA and textB`,  and returns.

Once the ajax call completes, the dialog shows up. I expect only one of the grids to show up based on the variable `choice`. It's initial value is `choiceA`. What happens is, the page loads with default choice A, I click the button, actionListener method sets `textA` and the dialog shows up. There is only one grid, as expected.

However, when I choose choiceB, it's still the same grid, `gridA`, that's displayed. In other words, the `rendered` attribute of the `p:panelGrid`s is only functioning correctly at page load, but is not updating on subsequent ajax calls. Strangely, `textA and textB` are updating well.

Below is the relevant part of the code.

```
<h:form>

    <p:selectOneRadio id="optionChoice" value="#{bean.choice}"
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="B" itemValue="choiceB" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="A" itemValue="choiceA" />
    </p:selectOneRadio>

    <p:commandButton value="Save"
        actionListener="#{bean.save}"
        update="dialogId"
        oncomplete="ajaxComplete(xhr, status, args)">

</h:form>

...

<p:dialog widgetVar="dialog" id="dialogId">

    <p:tabView id="tabViewX">
        <p:tab id="tabA" title="Tab A">

            <h:panelGrid id="gridA" rendered="#{bean.choice eq 'choiceA'}">
                <p:inputTextarea value="#{bean.textA}" />
                <h:button />
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:panelGrid id="gridB" rendered="#{bean.choice eq 'choiceB'}">
                <p:inputTextarea value="#{bean.textB}" />
            </h:panelGrid>

        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
</p:dialog>
```

Any suggestions why the `update` attribute of the `p:commandButton` updates only the `inputTextArea's value` but not the `panelGrid's rendered`?

I've also tried `update="tabViewX:gridA tabViewX:gridB"`. Not working either.

JSF version: Mojarra JSF API (javax.faces/2.1) 2.1.5 (20111123- SNAPSHOT). Primefaces 3.0.0 – Murat 2 mins ago edit

Comment: How does the ajax response look like?

Comment: How are you preventing cached AJAX calls?

Comment: @Diodeus: JSF does that by default already.

Comment: The Ajax response is: `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response><changes><update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[-7070639949954948643:7956900961496590964]]></update><extension ln="primefaces" type="args">{"validationOk":true}</extension></changes></partial-response>`

Comment: So the dialog isn't updated at all. I already wasn't sure if it was real code or a red herring, but you said that the inputs are been updated. Now, this is impossible with this response, I'll post an answer.

Comment: BalusC, unfortunately I posted an incorrect response, left from something else. I added a comment to your answer, and sorry for the mistake.

Comment: No problem. Well, I don't know what the problem could be in this case. The code posted so far looks fine. Which JSF impl/version and which PrimeFaces version are you using?

Comment: @BalusC - I'm using JSF 2.1 and Primefaces 3.0

Comment: That's not specific enough. Mojarra 2.1.0 and PrimeFaces 3.0 Final? Or Mojarra 2.1.6 and PrimeFaces 3.0.1? I need this information so that I (or others) can try to reproduce it myself on local playground  environment sooner or later. The version information is important to exclude version-specific bugs/features.

Comment: @BalusC - It's not Primefaces 3.0.1 but 3.0. So I guess its 3.0 Final. How do I look up JSF impl version? And can you suggest a workaround - or a different way to do this rather than using rendered?

Comment: For the JSF version you can lookup your ivy.xml or pom.xml. Or even in the libraries tab of Java Build path if you have created a new Dynamic Web Project and selected configuration and added libararies in eclipse. If still you didn't find it extract the jars using some archive utility like 7-zip and there is a file called MANIFEST.MF in META-INF folder open it with an editor and you will find there.

Comment: JSF version: Mojarra JSF API (javax.faces/2.1) 2.1.5 (20111123-
 SNAPSHOT). Primefaces 3.0.0

Comment: However, I ran the same code on my other computer, which has an older version of JSF. It's the exact same problem there :(